# TextView of white text

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to achieve the background effect of the TextView at the bottom of the below image.
sorry for my poor english...
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the image's text view?

Comment: Are you changing the colour of textview at run-time?

Comment: Use setBackground method and create a custom drawable with gradient.

Comment: Sorry fo my poor english.It means the background of the TextView whose text color is white.

Comment: set background color of textview to any other than white.
in xml use this: android:background="#ffff00"

Comment: I want to achieve the background effect of the TextView that is on the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your background drawable

your_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#fff"
        android:startColor="#c86e6e6e"
        android:gradientRadius="100dp"
        android:type="radial"/>
</shape>
```

And add to textview:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@drawable/your_drawable"
        android:padding="90dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use gradient scale. go Check documentation for more details